# I want to add data from my php database into my checkbox how can i do that?

Tags: android, json, url, android-intent, android-activity

I'm building an app to call, message and email from my My-SQL database. i want to fetch contacts/email from db to a Check box. the app will initiate from a log in screen. its an app for teachers in the college to send important data to students

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loading bar with an async task to receive the data and send to the other activity as parameter.